# Why can't Mathematica evaluate this integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, numerical-integration, function-construction, special-functions

I want to work with the rectangle function, which I define by

```
f[x_, m_] := Limit[1/((2*(x - m))^(2*k) + 1), k -> Infinity];
```

(I know that in theory I can use `HeavisidePi[x-m]` to obtain the same function, but using my definition evaluates to `1/2` at the discontinuities, which I want to retain.)

Clearly, the integral of `f` with respect to `x` over `{x, m - 1/2, m + 1/2}` should evaluate to `1`. However, I can't persuade Mathematica to define the integral at all: the code

```
Clear["Global`*"]; 
f[x_, m_] := Limit[1/((2*(x - m))^(2*k) + 1), k -> Infinity]; 
Module[{m = 0}, Plot[f[x, m], {x, -1, 1}, GridLines -> Automatic]]
Module[{m = 0}, Integrate[f[x, m], {x, m - 1/2, m + 1/2}]]
```

yields the desired plot, but returns `Undefined` for the integral.

I have tried adding `Assumptions` but clearly not the right ones, because it doesn't work. I have tried using `NIntegrate`, but it doesn't work. I have tried changing the definition of `f` to `HeavisidePi[x-m]` (which I don't want to do anyway), but it doesn't work. I have tried using a `Piecewise` definition - same non-result...

How do I obtain the correct result?

Comment: Does `f[x, 0]` evaluate correctly?

Comment: That limit evaluates to `ConditionalExpression[0, Log[2 x] > 0]`. It's not clear to me what `Integrate` will be able to do with it. I will suggest that if you want a Heaviside function but with a value at the origin, create it with `Piecewise`.

Comment: Why not using `HeavisidePi`? It keeps `HeavisidePi[1/2]` and `HeavisidePi[-1/2]` unevaluated. If some of your outputs contain `HeavisidePi[1/2]` you can simply replace it with desired value - like `HeavisidePi[1/2]->1/2` or `HeavisidePi[-1/2]->1/2`.

Comment: Hi all. In answer to your questions: (1) `f[0,0]` evaluates correctly to `1`; (2) @Daniel, I'm not sure I understand the reservation: at least until the limit `->Infinity` is reached, `f` is an entire (and therefore integrable) function - and in the limit the definite integral described clearly produces `1` (having said this, I did try `Piecewise` but that didn't work either, any least with the half-values at the discontinuities); (3) As mentioned in the OP, `HeavisidePi` also produces an `Undefined` result under integration.

Comment: When did you get `Undefined`? `Integrate[HeavisidePi[x - m], {x, m - 1/2, m + 1/2}] /. m -> 0` nicely evaluates into `1`.

Comment: My question was about `f[x, 0]`, which does not evaluate correctly, imo.  It was not about `f[0,0]`.  In `Integrate[]`, you're evaluating `f[x,0]`, so understanding what it does is the key.

Comment: Hi @azerbajdzan. The issue must be with the definition, then; because if I predefine `f` and write `f[x_, m_] := HeavisidePi[x - m];Integrate[f[x, 0], {x, -(1/2), 1/2}]`, I get `Undefined`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do integration first and then take the limit k-> inf.

Use indefinite integration. `Integrate`  only finds a solution for m==0.

```
g[x_, m_, k_] = 1/((2*(x - m))^(2*k) + 1)

mint[x_, k_] = Integrate[g[x, 0, k], x]

(*   x Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1/(2 k), 1 + 1/(2 k), -4^k x^(2 k)]   *)
```

Use a trick. Tell `Limit`  that x^(2 k) is always positive. (Valid for Integer k)
That is only neccessary for x== -1/2. For all other positive and negative x `Limit[mint[x, k], k -> \[Infinity]]`  is x. Maybe this is a removable singularity at x== -1/2 ?

```
mint2[x_, k_] = mint[x, k] /. x^(2 k) -> Abs[x]^(2 k)

Limit[mint2[1/2, k] - mint2[-1/2, k], k -> \[Infinity]]

(*   1   *)
```

A graphic shows the same.

```
Manipulate[Plot[mint[x, k], {x, -.5, .5}], {k, 1, 1000}]
```

Rubi (https://rulebasedintegration.org/) does the integral with arbitrary m.

```
rint[x_, m_, k_] = Int[g[x, m, k], x]

(*   (-m + x) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1/(2 k), 
       1/2 (2 + 1/k), -4^k (-m + x)^(2 k)]   *)

rint2[x_, m_, k_] = 
    rint[x, m, k] /. (-m + x)^(2 k) -> Abs[(-m + x)]^(2 k)

Limit[rint2[m + 1/2, m, k] - rint2[m - 1/2, m, k], k -> \[Infinity]]

(*   1   *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

```
f2[x_?NumericQ, m_] := Limit[1/((2*(x - m))^(2*k) + 1), k -> Infinity];

Module[{m = 0}, NIntegrate[f2[x, m], {x, m - 1/2, m + 1/2}]]

(* 1. *)
```

Comment: Many thanks to you both.